# Emq mqtt clustering : Client Session management

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing, mqtt, erlang-otp, emq

I've gone through the documentation for emq [clustering](https://docs.emqx.io/broker/v3/en/cluster.html) but i couldn't find a clear explanation for how session management is done. I understand topics table is shared among clustered nodes but client connection information is not? What happens if a node goes down? Would it loose all the info about client sessions it was managing?

Answer (score 0):

The route is shared in the cluster, and the session is stored on the connected node. If the node goes down and the client reconnects, the session will be lost.

https://docs.emqx.io/tutorial/latest/en/backend/whats_backend.html

Comment: Hi, the link doesn't work anymore.